# How to align a variable-height div next to a fixed-height div?

Tags: css

In my HTML I'm trying to align a Title next to the title's Bullet, so that the first line of the title always is next to the bullet, and the second line (if any) doesn't change the title's position - it just trails to the next line.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ebqq8/

HML:

```
<div class="bullet-container">
    <div class="bullet-title-container">
        <div class="circle-container">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <p class="bullet-title">Short Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bullet-details-container">
        <p>Body Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle-container {
    height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 14px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    /* width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal */
}
.bullet-title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
    min-height: 34px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.bullet-title-container {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
}
.bullet-details-container {
    color: black;
}
.bullet-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

What's happening now is that the first line is always too low, and if there are multiple lines, the whole title gets pushed up too high.  I thought that aligning two inline-block elements would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to be working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

to `.bullet-title { }`

http://jsfiddle.net/Ebqq8/2/